# Using XLwings to update Excel File from Python : OSError: [WinError -2147467259] Unspecified error

Tags: python, xlwings

I am using xlwings in python to read excel file and add my dataframe in excel file. Earlier my code was working fine but since yesterday its giving error as below :

***OSError: [WinError -2147467259] Unspecified error***

**Code:**

```
app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = xw.Book(file_path)  
ws = wb.sheets[1]
ws.range(A2).options(index=False).value = df
wb.save()
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

Error is coming on the second line of code where it tries to open the book.
wb = xw.Book(file_path)

Comment: Read this issue as a first off **https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1327**.

Comment: Rebooting my PC worked for me! I killed all the running excel instances from task manager and rebooted my PC and the code is running now.

Answer (score 2):

Complementary to moken's comment: Using [`with xw.App(visible=False) as app:`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.App) (available since Version 0.24.3) is more stable than `app = xw.App(visible=False)`, because it ensures that everything is properly cleaned up again and to prevent zombie processes after an error. Here is an example:

```
import xlwings as xw

path = r"test.xlsx"

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(path)
    ws = wb.sheets[1]
    ws.range("A2").options(index=False).value = df
    wb.save(path)
    wb.close()
```