# Pytest doesn't work with psutil + xlwings

Tags: python, pytest, xlwings, psutil

I found [another SO addressing a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679282/error-long-traceback-when-running-pytest-and-psutil) but no one gave an answer.

My problem is the following (and a bit simpler to reproduce), create a file called `test_file.py` with:

```py
import psutil
import xlwings

def test() -> None:
    my_function()

def my_function() -> None:
    # Create a new workbook
    wb = xlwings.Book()
    # Save it
    wb.save('test.xlsx')
    # Close it
    wb.close()

    # Kill zombie processes
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == "EXCEL.EXE":
            proc.kill()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_function()
```

When doing `python test_file.py`, everything goes smoothly.
When doing `pytest` to do my unit tests, I have this error:

```py
test_file.py Windows fatal exception: code 0x800706ba
```

The traceback is the following:

```py
  File "C:\Users\....\Desktop\so\test_file.py", line 6 in test
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 195 in pytest_pyfunc_call
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1789 in runtest
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 167 in pytest_runtest_call
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 260 in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 339 in from_call
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 259 in call_runtest_hook
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 220 in call_and_report
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 131 in runtestprotocol
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 112 in pytest_runtest_protocol
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 349 in pytest_runtestloop
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 324 in _main
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 270 in wrap_session
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 317 in pytest_cmdline_main
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 167 in main
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 190 in console_main
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pytest.exe\__main__.py", line 7 in <module>
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88 in _run_code
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198 in _run_module_as_main
```

It must be a problem between `pytest`, `xlwings`, `psutil` because if I'm not using the three simultaneously I cannot reproduce the bug.

I'm using `Python 3.11.1`, `xlwings==0.28.6`, `pytest==7.2.2` and `psutil==5.9.4`.

Using a context manager as suggested by @moken doesn't work either:

```py
import xlwings

def test() -> None:
    my_function()

def my_function() -> None:
    with xlwings.App(visible=True):
        # Create a new workbook
        wb = xlwings.Book()
        # Save it
        wb.save('test.xlsx')
        # Close it
        wb.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_function()
```

raises the exact same error (when using `pytest`, when not, everything works fine obviously).
[image]

Comment: It's the zombie process check that causes the error right? Why do that? like the referenced SO post suggests. Use a context manager to avoid zombie Excel processes.

Comment: The context manager raises the same exception for me. I've edited the main post.

Comment: Have you tried using `unittest.mock` to mock Excel interactions during testing to avoid the issue with (pytest, xlwings, and psutil)? As long as you know xlwings works fine with excel; this approach may work better.

Comment: The `.xlsx` which you are using in the pytest, make sure it's been closed. And also you can try running the pytest in a separate `subprocess`.

Comment: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1494 ?

Comment: @mrxra Thanks for the github issue reference! the github link you sent says:
"While I agree that that for internal unit testing, you can potentially disable faulthandling, I would advise against making use of -p no:faulthandler the official recommendation in your documentation, since users of the package (like me) would be unintentionally silencing all faulthandling -- not just the faulthandling for tests involving xlwings API calls.". Is it really safe to disable segmentation errors handling?

Comment: @mrxra About the stackoverflow you linked, I literally linked it and am actively talking about it in the post. I have no idea why you commented that.

Comment: @mrxra did you see my answers?

Comment: @IHopeItWontBeAStupidQuestion ...I have. I'm confused though by your comment regarding some stackoverflow link?...I did _not_ link _stackoverflow_, _but_ a bug report in the xlwings _github_ repo in hopes it might provide you with a workaround worth looking into - since the symptoms you described in your post seemed to be related. As you figured, and I agree, it's workaround, not a prod grade solution...but then again I would strongly advise against using xlwings in prod in general, in particular if you just need to write xlsx files (no excel automation) from a python script....

Comment: @IHopeItWontBeAStupidQuestion ...I also haven't looked into your issue in detail, because I neither use windows nor xlwings, hence I have no way of reproducing it. So I'm afraid I can't help you there.

Comment: @IHopeItWontBeAStupidQuestion ...you might want to try openpyxl if you are just reading/writing xlsx files....contrary to xlwings it only depends on the format specification and does no shaky excel automation magic (which is probably why xlwings hasn't reached a major version yet)